# How to take output from a if condition?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, centos, output

I don't if this method is applicable or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
if [[ -x "$file" ]]
then
if [ $? = 0 ]
then 
echo $file is executable
else
echo $file is not executable
fi
fi
```

But if i run this script with a non executable file it returns nothing
But if i run this script with a executable file it returns "name is executable"

> > just want to know about positional parameter working. i'm a beginner.but can i 
> >     take the output of the first if condition into $?

Comment: Your first if already tests if the file is executable. What's the purpose of the nested one?

Comment: just want to know about positional parameter working. i'm a beginner.but can i take the output of the first if condition into $?

Comment: @BenjaminM.J : To answer the first part of your question: The positional parameter `1 ` is stored into the shell variable `file`. Since this is the only place in your script, where the positional parameter is used, I don't understand what you still want to know about it.

Comment: @BenjaminM.J : If you run the script with a non-executable file, `[[ -x "$file" ]]` is false, and you don't have an `else` part. Therefore, you don't get anything printed.

Answer (score 0):

For such test you do not need the internal if. THis code will do the work:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
if [[ -x "$file" ]]
 then
   echo $file is executable
 else
   echo $file is not executable
fi
```

Comment: just want to know about positional parameter working. i'm a beginner.but can i take the output of the first if condition into $?

Comment: @BenjaminM.J you have it already (in different form). If its true you exec `then` if its false you exec `else`

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Not clear what you are asking. Of course any `echo` command will clear `$?`, but I don't see why this would be a problem here. If you really need the $? to be preserved, just invoke `false` after printing that the file is not executable.

Comment: @user1934428, as you can see I do not need anythings here. I provide answer!

Comment: Sorry, RomeoNinov, my comment was supposed to go to the OP. By mistake, I typed your name in the comment. But while we are at it: Maybe it makes sense that you indeed add a `false` to the else-branch of your solution, as I suggested, so that the OP happily can verify that `$?` is still the same afterwards.

Comment: @user1934428, IMHO this is not need as in `else` clause OP can add assign of any variable. So keep track of `$?` is not required.

Comment: @RomeoNinov : It is not required, but I could imagne one case where this is handy: If this is the last statement in your shell script, and you have your `PS1` configured to show somehow the status code of the most recent statement, or alternatively if you want to invoke this script from another script and want to evaluate the exit code, it makes more sense to have it in `$?` instead of your own variable. Admittedly, as long as the OP does not reveal why he needs `$?` to be set up in this way, we can only make a wild guess.

Comment: @user1934428, abut exit codes there is command `exit` which can have value from 0 to 255 and will work in your examples. And I do not see difference between compare `$?` and any other variable.

Comment: It is not necessarily about comparision. In PS1, you have an escape code for uniformely displaying `$?`. Of course writing an explicitly `exit` is one possibility, but since the OP seems to want to have `$?` being preserved, it does not harm IMO to show how this can be done.